# Return only queries with an attribute set an explicit value in Algolia

Tags: javascript, algolia

Is it possible to setup the front-end of Algolia so that it will only return results that have a passed attribute equal an explicitly set value AS WELL as the users query?

So the user queries for `red shoes`, but I want to only give them the results that match `red shoes` AND where `prices.isHigh` is equal to `20` (as an example)?

I was thinking of passing something like `attributesToRetrieve: 'prices.isHigh:20'` or maybe `numericFilters: 'prices.isHigh:20'`. Using the JavaScript API.

Would either of those work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave the solution in your question:

```coffee
{
  query: 'red shoes',
  numericFilters: 'prices.isHigh=20'
}
```

[`attributesToRetrieve`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#param-attributesToRetrieve) on the other hand is used to restrict which attributes you want in the response to reduce the JSON size and can be overriden at query time. It expect a list of attributes. For security purposes, you can instead set the [`unretrievableAttributes`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#param-unretrievableAttributes) index setting that isn't overridable.

Comment: Hmm do you know how I would actually configure that in the JavaScript client? I've put `{ numericFilters: 'prices.isHigh:20' }` and I get an error: "Invalid syntax for numeric condition:prices.isHigh:20"

Comment: Ah, should be `prices.isHigh=20` with `=` instead of `:`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited my answer to fix this.